# Converting array of Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] to list of List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, func, system.reflection

Is that possible to convert array of `params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] includeProperties`

to array of `List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> propertiesInfo`?

If yes, please explain how can I do it?

TModel is a class

***EDITED:***

My purpose of this action is that I can assign just some properties of an object to another object.
My method for this goal is:

```
public static void Assign(this object destination, object source,   List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> includeProperties)
    {
        if (destination is IEnumerable && source is IEnumerable)
        {
            var dest_enumerator = (destination as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
            var src_enumerator = (source as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
            while (dest_enumerator.MoveNext() && src_enumerator.MoveNext())
                dest_enumerator.Current.Assign(src_enumerator.Current);
        }
        else
        {
            //var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo destProperty in includeProperties)
                {
                    if (destProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name && destProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
                    {
                        destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, new object[] { }), new object[] { });
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

another method:

```
public virtual void Update(object viewModel, params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> pList = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        foreach (var prop in includeProperties)
        {
            //Todo: I should convert prop to PropertyInfo and then add to pList 
        }
        using (new EFUnitOfWorkFactory().Create())
        {
            TModel model = new TModel();
            model.Assign(viewModel, pList);
            RepositoryContainer<TRepository>().Update(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand: how do you expect to retrieve a property from a `Func<TModel, object>`? does the function return the property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've broken this down into two parts:

Part 1: Extracting a `PropertyInfo` from an `Expression<Func<T, object>>`:

```
public static class ExpressionUtil
{
    public static PropertyInfo Property<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        var member = ExpressionUtil.Member(expr);
        var prop = member as PropertyInfo;

        if (prop == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Specified member is not a property.");
        }

        return prop;
    }

    public static MemberInfo Member<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        // This is a tricky case because of the "object" return type.
        // An expression which targets a value type property will
        // have a UnaryExpression body, whereas an expression which
        // targets a reference type property will have a MemberExpression
        // (or, more specifically, PropertyExpression) Body.
        var unaryExpr = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
        var memberExpr = (MemberExpression)(unaryExpr == null ? expr.Body : unaryExpr.Operand);

        return memberExpr.Member;
    }
}
```

Part 2: Performing the projection to get `List<PropertyInfo>`:

```
// includeProperties is Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[].
List<PropertyInfo> pList = includeProperties
    .Select(ExpressionUtil.Property)
    .ToList();
```

... or (plugging it into your existing code):

```
List<PropertyInfo> pList = new List<PropertyInfo>();

foreach (var prop in includeProperties)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = ExpressionUtil.Property(prop);

    pList.Add(pi);
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so now we know that your array in fact contains a mix of different expression trees (those targeting value type properties, and those targeting reference type properties). The below will handle both:

```
List<PropertyInfo> pList = new List<PropertyInfo>();

foreach (var prop in includeProperties)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpr = prop.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (memberExpr == null)
    {
        UnaryExpression unaryExpr = (UnaryExpression)prop.Body;

        memberExpr = (MemberExpression)unaryExpr.Operand;
    }

    PropertyInfo pi = (PropertyInfo)memberExpr.Member;

    pList.Add(pi);
}
```

I have tweaked `ExpressionUtil.Member` to work correctly in your case as well as the general case which I originally wrote it for.

**Final word**

Now that I've laid out what you *could* do to make things work using the BCL I would like to point out that the problem of mapping entities is ubiquitous and there are a number of specialised third-party tools which address it very well - i.e. AutoMapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: I got an exception in Member<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression'.

one of my parameter is m=>m.Title that Title is string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your trying, but still there is the problem.
if my parameter be m=>m.Id or m=>m.IsActive that Id is int and IsActive is bool, I face an exception.....

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.

Comment: @Jahan, please see my latest edit (I've changed `ExpressionUtil.Member<T>` and plain example in the *edit* section to handle unary as well as non-unary expressions). As it stands *all* code examples above should work for you. If they don't please let me know and I'll investigate further.

Comment: By the way, I completely misdiagnosed the `UnaryExpression` vs `MemberExpression` issue initially blaming it (quite erroneously) on delegate variance whereas in fact it could not have been the issue here (`Expression` is a class, not a delegate). For that I apologise. The reason different expressions behave differently is due to the return type of `Func<T, object>` (that is, `object`), which means that expressions targeting reference type properties have a `MemberExpression` Body, but expressions targeting value type properties require boxing - hence the extra `UnaryExpression` involved.